# HTML Submit form on dropdown change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**Good morning!**

I know that this topic has been covered on SO before but I couldn't find the full answer to my specific situation below so I apologize if I missed the answer elsewhere.

**Scope:**

What I am trying to achieve is a drop down list (either done with pure HTML or java script, HTML is preferred) that can load a php file. Inside that php file it should be able to access the selected drop down's value.

**What I have tried:**

---

*Method 1:*

I have used a method like this before:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
<option value="value1">Option 1</option>
<option value="value2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<input name="submitbutton" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Then clicking on the submit button, the test.php page loads and I can get the value of the dropdown using $_POST("dropdown"). This method works perfectly fine! However I want to submit the form WITHOUT need of the button, simply using the drop down onchange event instead.

---

*Method 2:*

I also tried using:

```
<form>
<select name='dropdown' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
<option value="value1">Option 1</option>
<option value="value2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
</form>
```

which will reload the page onchange but not the test.php page.. Changing "this.form.submit()" to test.php doesn't work.

---

I feel like I am close with both but not quite there. I hope what I am trying to achieve is explained well enough.

Thank you for any responses ahead of time!

Comment: you are missing the action fro the form tag in your second example - thats why the page refreshes rather than posting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
```

To method2 and it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Give your form a name:

```
<form name="form1" action="test.php">
```

....then your onchange would be: `document.form1.submit();`

BTW, this has nothing to do with PHP, since it is 100% on the client.

Comment: Thank you for your response however I need it to load test.php onchange, not just refresh it's own page. It has to do with PHP because I want the test.php file to be able to get the dropdown's value. Hope this is more clear now.

Comment: Add "action=test.php", and no, this still has nothing to do with PHP - that's just the post URL on the server. It could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add '`action="test.php"`' and '`method="post"`' in your for tag.. So, your IInd method should like below:

**HTML Code:**

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<select name='dropdown' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
<option value="value1">Option 1</option>
<option value="value2">Option 2</option>
</select>
    <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></noscript>
</form>
```

and it will work and you can show your post data with `print_r($_POST)` in `test.php`. It will show you `dropdown` value :)

Comment: Yours works too but Michal Hubczyk answered first so I marked his as the answer :) Thanks though!

Comment: @EricF: No prob :) Stackoverflow is always for good learning, sharing and caring.

Comment: I agree! I always come here when I get stuck and also try to answer questions. I am very new to HTML and webpages but quite experienced in other languages. It is an excellent concept for helping everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using with ajax

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("change", "select#dropdown", function(){
    $.ajax({
         url: 'http://localhost/test/action.php',
         type: "post",
         data: $("#myform").serialize();,
         success: function(response) {
             $('select#dropdown').after("dropdown changed!");
         }
    });
});
```